# How to express $f(x)=\lfloor\sin{x}\rfloor$ in multi-line equation form.

Tags: algebra-precalculus

How to express $f(x)=\lfloor\sin{x}\rfloor$ in multi-line equation form (in Case form), $x\in \mathbb{R}$.

Attempt [image]

$\lfloor\sin x\rfloor =\cases{ 1,& sin x=1 \cr
 0,& $0 \leq \sin x<1$ \cr 
-1,& $-1\leq \sin{x}<0$ }$

then 
$f(x) =
  \begin{cases}
   1     & \quad \text{if } x=2n\pi+\pi/2\\
   0  & \quad \text{if } x ~\text{lies in 1st or 2nd quadrant except} ~x=2n\pi+\pi/2 \\
-1& \quad \text{if } x ~\text{lies in 3rd or 4th  quadrant}\\
  \end{cases}$

Please help me to write $f(x)$ in more simply and mathematically sound.

Comment: Are you trying to express your function $\;f\;$ *only* for values on the trigonometric circle? I think you are not, but then I don't understand the use of "first ,second" or whatever *quadrant* ...

Comment: @DonAntonio I want to know $f(x)=1,0,-1$ for what values of $x$

Comment: I've added an answer assuming we already know the main values on the trigonometric circle and then we just use periodicity.

Comment: @DonAntonio $f(x)=[\sin x]=-1$ if x lies in entire 3rd and 4th quatrant i.e $(-2\pi, -\pi)$ and etc, not only at $x=\frac{3\pi}2+2k\pi$

Comment: True. I shall edit now.

Answer (score 1):

I'd say that for any $\;x\in\Bbb R\;$ , the simplest and perhaps one of the clearest ways could be:

$$f(x)=\begin{cases}1,&x=\frac\pi2+2k\pi\;,\;\;k\in\Bbb Z\\{}\\-1,&x=t+2k\pi\,,\,\,\pi< t<2\pi\;,\;\;k\in\Bbb Z\\{}\\
0,&\text{otherwise}\end{cases}$$

Comment: Very good presentation. If I want to change "otherwise" in your style, what it would be. $x=t+2k\pi\,,\,\,\0< t<\pi, x\neq \frac\pi2+2k\pi\;,\;\;k\in\Bbb Z$

Comment: You could try $\;x=t+2k\pi\;,\;\;t\in\left[0,\,\pi\right]\setminus\left\{\frac\pi2\right\}\;$ ...basically, as you wrote it.

Comment: Your x only excludes $\pi/2$, but $3\pi/2$ etc are not excluded

Comment: @user1942348 I don't understand: in my answer all $\;x\;$ is included, also $\;\frac\pi2\;$ ...

Comment: In $\;x=t+2k\pi\;,\;\;t\in\left[0,\,\pi\right]\setminus\left\{\frac\pi2\right\}\;$ only $\pi/2$ is excuded, but other $3\pi/2$, $5\pi/2$ etc i.e $\frac\pi2+2k\pi$ should also be excluded.

Comment: @user1942348 But that was *only* for that part of the definition. In the other parts we take care of all real values, as far as I can see...